# Filter Results Before FirstOrDefault() and Then Using FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to do something like that;

```
Context.Users.Include("Addresses", a => a.IsRowDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 5);
```

I mean; I want to filter included entities but not always, its also have to be optional.

What is the best solution for this? Please help me,

Comment: can you please be more clear with what you want to ask? will be good if you can give example. Where is include defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot filter eager loaded data in EF. `Include` operation doesn't support filtering or sorting.

You must use either projection to custom type (or anonymous type):

```
var query = from u in context.Users
            where u.UserId == 5
            select new UserFiltered 
                { 
                    User = u,
                    Addresses = u.Addresses.Where(a => !a.IsRowDeleted)
                };
UserFiltered u = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you must devide your query into two separated queries and use explicit loading:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 5);
((EntityCollection<Address>)user.Addresses)
     .CreateSourceQuery()
     .Where(a => !a.IsRowDeleted)
     .Execute();
```

Or you can simply use two queries:

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 5);
var addresses = context.Addresses.Where(a => a.User.UserId == 5 && !a.IsRowDeleted).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like (warning: untested code):

```
Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Addresses.Where(a => a.IsRowDeleted == false).Count > 0) && u.UserId == 5);
```